# join tables with using max mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables with one to one relationship, the first is "book" and the second is "payment", I want to get the (cus_id) from "book"with the highest (price) from payment using join, which means i have to use max, but i can not get the right syntax for this

> book has these columns (cus_id, inv_id as FK,....) and payment has (inv_id as PK, price,...)

```
I tried this syntax
select b.cus_id, p.price 
from customer b, payment p
where b.inv_id=p.inv_id;
```

but this syntax absolutely won't give me the max price, and here i need the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select a.cus_id,max(price)
from book a,payment
where a.inv_id = (Select b.inv_id from payment b where price = (select max(price) from payment))
```

Comment: this gives me an error: unknown column 'b.price' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.cus_id, p.price from customer b, payment p where b.inv_id=p.inv_id AND p.price = (SELECT max(price) FROM payment WHERE inv = p.inv)
```

if you need only a specific book, add another filter for it